# angular, filter out unique combinations of two parameters

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, filter, unique

is it possible to filter an array with `unique` with two criteria ?

Instead of this:

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in data | unique:{'model'}"></ion-item>
```

I would like to filter only unique combinations of two parameters :

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in data | unique:{['brand','model']}"></ion-item>
```

For example I need the filter to keep:

```
brand: 'Matta'  model: 'gravy'
brand: 'CI'  model: 'gravy'
```

but to remove one of those two:

```
brand: 'Matta'  model: 'gravy'
brand: 'Matta'  model: 'gravy'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always pipe the filters, so try this out:

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in data | unique:{'brand'} | unique:{'model'}"></ion-item>
```

The first filter takes the first array and outputs an array with the filter applied. the second filter uses the first one's output and does the same. The result is the array with both filters applied.

EDIT:
To achieve getting the unique combination you can use a custom filter like this one:

```
app.filter('filterObj', filterObj);

function filterObj() {
  return function(collection, properties) {
    var trace = [];
    angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      for (var i = 0; i < trace.length; i++) {
         if (equalsPartial(item, trace[i], properties))
           return;
      }
      trace.push(item);
    });
    return trace;
  }

    function equalsPartial(item,traceItem,properties){
        for (var j = 0; j < properties.length; j++) {
          if (item[properties[j]] !== traceItem[properties[j]])
            return false;
        }
      return true;
    }
}
```

And then you use it:

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in data | filterObj: ['brand','model']"></ion-item>
```

The filter adds the items to a new array after checking if the new array already contains an item that shares the same properties, if it exists it does nothing, else it adds it.
You can take the equalsPartial function and put it in another filter as well.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/tinchomm/pen/PWzOao)

Comment: Ok thanks, but maybe I wasn't clear enough : I need to filter to get only the unique pairs brand/model... I am editing the question

Comment: Great this custom function seems to work for me, thanks a lot